# I am unable to display my text in two grid columns and center it

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```css
.hero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 33.45rem);
  grid-template-rows: 12.5rem;
  border-bottom: .05em solid #05d31f;
  width: 69.8rem;
  height: 16.5rem;

}

.hero-title {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.hero-title h2 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0.2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.3rem;
}

.hero-text {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column: span 2;
  align-items: center;
}

.hero-text p {
  font-size: .7rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div className="hero">
      <div className="hero-title">
          <h2>FrontEnd Development with CLASS</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="hero-text">
          <p>
          I am a Front End Web developer with a passion for 
          building scalable, maintainable, and accessible 
          web applications. I have a strong background in
          HTML, CSS, Javascript, and REACT. I am always looking
          for new challenges and
          opportunities to grow and learn.
          </p>
      </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I am trying to display the text in the middle of my grid columns;
but I can't get it  span both columns; do I need to use positioning ? I have tried using
align-items: width 100% and also making it a certain width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```css
.hero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 0.05em solid #05d31f;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.hero-title,
.hero-text {
  text-align: left;
}
.hero-title h2 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}
.hero-text p {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero-title">
    <h2>FrontEnd Development with CLASS</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-text">
    <p>
      I am a Front End Web developer with a passion for 
      building scalable, maintainable, and accessible 
      web applications. I have a strong background in
      HTML, CSS, Javascript, and REACT. I am always looking
      for new challenges and opportunities to grow and learn.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Today I read your case again and I was intrigued by this sentence (not very clear to me):

> *I am trying to **display the text in the middle of my grid columns**;*
> *but I can't get it span both columns; do I need to use positioning ?*

```css
.hero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 0.05em solid #05d31f;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.hero-title,
.hero-text, {
  text-align: left;
}

.centered-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: #05d31f;
}

.hero-title h2 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}

.hero-text p {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}

.centered-text {
  grid-column: span 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="centered-text" span-columns>
    <p>
      I am trying to display the text in the middle of my grid columns;
      but I can't get it to span both columns; do I need to use positioning? 
      I have tried using align-items: width 100% and also making it a certain width and height.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-title">
    <h2>FrontEnd Development with CLASS</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-text">
    <p>
      I am a Front End Web developer with a passion for 
      building scalable, maintainable, and accessible 
      web applications. I have a strong background in
      HTML, CSS, Javascript, and REACT. I am always looking
      for new challenges and opportunities to grow and learn.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```